# Making final class variables static in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

In Java when a `final` field is assigned a constant value compile-time, it usually makes sense declaring it `static`. It saves overhead according to the relevant PMD rule.

Does it make any sense or difference doing it in GWT regarding the generated Javascript code?

Comment: Where did you read that a final variable should be made static? The opposite may be true as a static variable usually is a sign of poor design, but it makes perfect sense to have a final non-static variable

Comment: Well, this is a PMD rule that is checked on my code. See http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/design.html chapter "FinalFieldCouldBeStatic"

Comment: Sorry but your text is completely misleading. The rule says that a final field with a constant value (like 42) can be make static. It does not say that a final variable should be made static. There is a huge difference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable is assigned when it is declared final, then yes, static makes a certain amount of sense, but there are cases where it should not be static:

```
public MyClassWithFinal {
    private final String finalVar;
    public MyClassWithFinal(String name) {
         this.finalVar = name;
    }
}
```

Another case: If the instance var is not a string or number constant, but requires running a constructor, that constructor may have side effects each time it is invoked, so running it only once is different than running it multiple times.

That said, GWT will inline/intern constant string values, so if you have multiple String fields all assigned to the same value, GWT will probably detect that and promote them all to static.

```
public final String constant = "Some Constant that really ought to be static";
```

GWT will notice that this is never assigned except when declared, and may even remove the field itself.

The best rule is to start with the best (i.e. most readable, most maintainable, most efficient) Java code, and to only break from that in cases where GWT requires something specific. This is not one of those cases: the compiler should perform the same basic optimizations no matter how you write this.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. So you say that for primitive types e.g. String it makes no sense due to GWT compiler optimalization, right?

Comment: Yes and no: The compiler will be pretty smart about final fields, but if something is always the same for all instances, you probably mean to use static - that's what I mean in the last paragraph about making it the most readable. If you you really want different instances of the field for each object, then leave out static, but those keywords aren't just there for the compiler, they convey useful info to future readers of your code.

Comment: The first code chunk in the answer is a case where PMD shouldn't complain about a final String field, and where it is not correct or useful to make it static. If something is a constant though, static may well make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

A field marked as final doesn't mean that it is immutable, only that its reference won't point to any other memory chunk. Therefore, it can only make sense to make a field static if it is really immutable, or if it is a primitive.

For instance, it's common to declare lists as final if you want to make sure that they will never point to a different list object, but the list itself can still be filled with data, cleared, filled again, etc. And of course, each object declaring such list does not mandatory want to share it among every instances.

```
private final List<...> list = new ArrayList<...>();
```

Final keyword is there to prevent you from doing mistakes, like setting to null a reference that should never change.

Comment: I feel a little bit that your answer is not really related to my GWT specific question. +1 anyways for the clarification.